# How do I insert a drop-down menu for a simple Windows Forms app in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, drop-down-menu

There appears to be every other kind of drop-down menu--those that allow user input, those for integers only, those that don't...drop down, and even those that have ugly check boxes next to them. I just want a simple drop-down menu (like you'd see if I used  in html) that lets the user choose exactly ONE item. (and one's chosen by default)

Any ideas? This should be extremely easy, yet I've spent an hour and half figuring this out...

Answer (score 47):

You can use a `ComboBox` with its `ComboBoxStyle` (appears as `DropDownStyle` in later versions) set to `DropDownList`.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use ComboBox, then point your mouse to the upper arrow facing right, it will unfold a box called ComboBox Tasks and in there you can go ahead and edit your items or fill in the items / strings one per line. This should be the easiest.

Comment: It might be nice to add a brief code sample to help out the poster and any future visitors too.

Comment: "point your mouse to the upper arrow facing right" -- I've used the ComboBox several times and I'm not even sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Singular1ty why didn't you also post your comment on the other answer? It also doesn't have a brief code sample